# how to ascending sort a multiple array of SPARK RDD by any column in scala?

Tags: arrays, scala, sorting, apache-spark, rdd

I'm interested in **apache SPARK.**

I tried to ascending sort a multiple array of SPARK RDD by any column in scala.

(i.e. `RDD[Array[Int] -> Array(Array(1,2,3), Array(2,3,4), Array(1,2,1))`

If I sort by first column, then result will be `Array(Array(1,2,3), Array(1,2,1), Array(2,3,4)).` or If I sort by third column, then result will be `Array(Array(1,2,3), Array(1,2,3), Array(2,3,4)).`
)
and then, I want to get RDD[Array[Int]] return-type value.
Is there a method to solve it, whether using `map()` or `filter()` function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
val baseRdd = sc.parallelize(Array(Array(1, 2, 3), Array(2, 3, 4), Array(1, 2, 1)))

//False specifies desending order 
val result = baseRdd.sortBy(x => x(1), false)

result.foreach { x => println(x(0) + "\t" + x(1) + "\t" + x(2)) }
```

**Result**

> 2 3 4
>
> 1 2 3
>
> 1  2   1

Comment: Could you answer one more question if you don't mind?
I want to make a new RDD array with some elements extracted from original RDD array.

(i.e. Here is a `RDD[Array[Int]] -> Array(Array(1,2,3), Array(2,3,4), Array(1,2,1).` 
And I want to make a new RDD array from original RDD array -> `Array(Array(1,2,3), Array(1,2,1))` like this.)

Is there a method to solve it?

Comment: Yes you can do that. one quick question. on what basis you want to extract data from ur original rdd ? that would help me to give u precise answer.

Comment: original rdd array means that `RDD[Array[Int]] -> Array(Array(1,2,3), Array(2,3,4), Array(1,2,1)).` 
As I say, I wanna make a new rdd array `(Array(Array(1,2,3), Array(1,2,1))` from RDD[Array[Int]] -> Array(Array(1,2,3), Array(2,3,4), Array(1,2,1)).` 
It's difficult to me...

Comment: you need to apply filter() method.  filter method will return true or false. I'm not sure what are your parameters to filter it. but giving one sample ..

Comment: val baseRdd = sc.parallelize(Array(Array(1, 2, 3), Array(2, 3, 4), Array(1, 2, 1)))

    val resultRDD = baseRdd.filter { x => x(1).!=(3) }

    resultRDD.foreach { x => println(x(0) + "\t" + x(1) + "\t" + x(2)) }

Comment: Hope this is helpful

Answer (score 2):

Use `RDD.sortBy`:

```
// sorting by second column (index = 1)
val result: RDD[Array[Int]] = rdd.sortBy(_(1), ascending = true)
```

The sorting function can also be written using Pattern Matching:

```
val result: RDD[Array[Int]] = rdd.sortBy( {
  case Array(a, b, c) => b /* choose column(s) to sort by */
}, ascending = true)
```

Also note the `ascending` argument's default value is `true`, so you can drop it and get the same result:

```
val result: RDD[Array[Int]] = rdd.sortBy(_(1))
```

Comment: It works.  Thank you, but could you answer one more question if you don't mind?  If I insert 4 or more dimension arrays, then I have to command by typing different case-statement.

Comment: Never Mind about my last comment.  Thank you~~